# Call mock methods instead of the library ones

Tags: c++, mocking

I am using a C library called BFciLib.h which has only definitions of methods that look
like this one:

```
 tCIRC  CiVFGopen(                  
        tCIU32          devNdx,     //!< from CiSysVFGinfo() 
        tCIU32          modeFlags,  //!< access mode flags 
        tCIp            *cip        //!< access token 
        );
```

This method (and others) is called from the methods of a class that i implemented called FGrabber, something like this:

```
 EXIT_ON_ERROR(CiVFGopen(deviceIndex, tCIboardOpenEnums::kCIBO_exclusiveWrAccess, &interface));
```

I have mocked CiVFGopen method to do what i want it to do (created a C wrapper and calling my implemented behavior) but i have no idea how to link it in my FGrabber class.

```
tCIRC CiVFGopen(tCIU32 devNdx, tCIU32 modeFlags, tCIp *interface)
{
       std::cout<<"entered the mock method";
       return tCIerrorCode::kCIEnoErr;
}
```

Because of this, i am getting an error: `multiple definition of CiVFGopen`

I am not allowed to edit FGrabber, it has to stay with its production form, and just find a way to link my mock method to be used instead of the original one.

I have found namespaces, but i do not think this is what i need, since it will require me to modify FGrabber class is it not?

Comment: Don't link to the original library, problem solved.

Comment: but i need to since it is the production code, and need to link my mock method for unit tests

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you want to do, but the error exists probably because you don't use the `inline` on the function definitions.

Try:

```
inline tCIRC  CiVFGopen(                  
        tCIU32          devNdx,     //!< from CiSysVFGinfo() 
        tCIU32          modeFlags,  //!< access mode flags 
        tCIp            *cip        //!< access token 
        );
```

Comment: http://www.bitflow.com/LinuxHelp/BFciLib_8h_source.html here is the library that i am using. they don't use inline there and neither am I

Comment: Are you linking to a library? If you are linking to a library that defines the code of the CiVFGopen and you are redefining the code then you will get that error too I think.